# How do you compute the stress-energy tensor for electromagnetism + gauge fixing term?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, gauge

I want to compute the stress-energy tensor for the following Lagrangian:
$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2\xi} (\nabla_\mu A^\mu)^2$$

but I'm struggling with the gauge-fixing term. When taking variations with respect to the metric, it seems that it will involve many terms, some of then not clearly covariant. I am only interested in its value in Minkowski, but that is also hard to find.

By stress-energy tensor I mean the Hilbert one, defined as:

$$T_{\mu \nu} = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}}$$

**My attempt**

I have attempted to include an auxiliary field, such that

$$\mathcal{L}' = -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} + B \nabla_\mu A^\mu + \frac{\xi}{2} B^2$$

which becomes the original one after finding and imposing the equations of motion for $B$. But is it true that the two stress energy tensors are going to be the same? What I find is that

$$T_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L} + F_{\alpha \mu} F_{\beta \nu} g^{\alpha \beta} + \frac{4}{\xi} \partial_\alpha A^\alpha \partial_{(\mu} A_{\nu)} + \frac{2}{\xi} \partial_{(\mu} \left(\partial_\alpha A^\alpha \right) A_{\nu)} - \frac{1}{\xi} \eta_{\mu \nu} \partial_\rho(A^\rho \partial_\alpha A^\alpha)$$

in Minkowski, and after getting rid of the auxiliary field. Can this be correct? What if I integrate by parts the first term involving the auxiliary field, so that I get:

$$\mathcal{L}' = -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} - \nabla_\mu B A^\mu + \frac{\xi}{2} B^2 = -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu} - \partial_\mu B A^\mu + \frac{\xi}{2} B^2 $$

given that $B$ is a scalar field. This seems to be giving me a different stress-energy tensor as well.

Comment: Did you try replacing  $\nabla_\mu A^\mu$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_\mu(\sqrt{|g|} A^\mu)$? I am almost certain it should work, but I don't currently have time to work out the details

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. What I tried is, given $\mathcal{L}$, use the definition of the covariant derivative and use the variation of the Christoffel symbols. That involves many terms that are not clearly covariant, I believe (i.e. $\nabla_\mu (\partial_\mu A^\nu A^\mu)$ [I am not saying that you get this term exactly, just that it involves this kind of terms])

Comment: Yup, that really sounds messy, but my approach is clearly coordinate independent so it  shouldn't be as messy

Comment: Notice that the energy-momentum tensor is not unique but can be modified by terms that vanish by the equations of motion. See e.g. http://max2.physics.sunysb.edu/~rastelli/HW2Solutions.pdf. The concept of these so-called improvement terms is widely known, but I am not sure I can point to a text book that discusses them. So it is perfectly conceivable that you get two seemingly different results as long as the difference is such an "improvement term".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it has been a week and I think I have convinced myself of the answer. Basically the solution was in the comments, but took me some time to understand. Indeed, as @marmot has said, the stress-energy tensor is an intrinsically off-shell object. Therefore, obtaining two seemingly different answer should not be a problem. Only when you project them on-shell (impose the equations of motion), you can expect to obtain a single, unique answer. .

The "two different" ways I propose of computing the tensor (i.e. with the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L'}$ containing $B \nabla_\mu A^\mu$ or, integrating by parts and using $\partial_\mu B A^\mu$), and the way that @Filipe Miguel explains (i.e. writing down the exact expression for the covariant derivative of $A^\mu$), end up giving the same answer after using the EOM.

Thank you very much everyone!